# ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host dependencies

Tags: ssh

I was attempting to install node.js from source. The post told me to install gcc-c++ and make. After this installation whenever I attempt to login using the command line I get this error.

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Based on the post [here](http://edoceo.com/notabene/ssh-exchange-identification) I figured out that it could be due to missing dependencies. A `lsof -n | grep ssh | grep DEL` on the server displays the following

```
sshd     24019 root     DEL     REG      0,4     249687548    /dev/zero
sshd     24019 root     DEL     REG      0,4     249687548    /dev/zero
sshd     24019 sridhar  DEL     REG      0,4     249687529    /dev/zero
sshd     24019 sridhar  DEL     REG      0,4     249687529    /dev/zero
```

I have removed gcc-c++ and make. But am unable to login. Is there a way to restore the dependencies so that ssh logins can be allowed.

Comment: post a verbose log from ssh to the host.

Comment: Show us what's in your server side sshd log. If necessary increase the log verbosity.

Comment: sridhar@sridhar-Aspire-5745:~$ ssh -v -p 9999 sridhar@999.999.999.99> /home/sridhar/Downloads/sshlog.txt
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 999.999.999.99 [999.999.999.99] port 9999.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/sridhar/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/sridhar/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/sridhar/.ssh/id_dsa type -1

Comment: @Iain Can't find the ssh logfiles in /var/log. My entrie in sshd_config is SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV

Comment: Perhaps it logs to secure or auth or somewhere else.

Comment: @Iain Thanks for the pointing out. SSH was logging into /var/log/secure. I monitored the logs and noticed that I was able to login from other laptops. I then realised that the problem could be something in my laptop. I restored my keys and I am able to login.

Comment: On hindsight looks like the install of GCC and MAKE had nothing to do with this issue.